# Search-ADAccount not returning EmployeeID/EmployeeNumber

Tags: powershell

I have a small script that looks through AD and finds user's EmployeeID numbers. But , Search-ADAccount was returning blank values for EmployeeID/EmployeeNumber for all users.

here is my code :

```
$expiredaccounts = Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan 30.00:00:00 | Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq $true } | Select-Object name, SamAccountName, AccountExpirationDate, EmployeeID|  ConvertTo-Html | Out-String

Send-MailMessage -to $emailto -Subject $subject -SmtpServer $smtp -From $fromaddress -Cc $emailcc -Body ($expiredaccounts) -BodyAsHtml
```

Comment: my understanding is that specific AD cmdlet returns ONLY the account object, not all the props for that object. i think you will need to use `Get-ADUser` & the `-Properties` parameter to get the full details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Search-ADAccount` doesn't return the `employeeID` attribute in its result set, and unfortunately doesn't support specifying extra attributes.

You can grab the `employeeID` value with a separate call to `Get-ADUser` in a calculated property:

```
$expiredaccounts = Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan 30.00:00:00 | Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq $true } 
$expiredaccounts | Select-Object name, SamAccountName, AccountExpirationDate, @{Name='EmployeeID';Expression={($_ |Get-ADUser -Properties employeeID).employeeID}}
```

Comment: Lastly  ,  When attempting to send mail then I am getting an error message like  `Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:53 char:93
+ ... maddress -Body ($expiredaccounts) -BodyAsHtml`